# "Cache-Control: max-age=0" Per-key cache invalidation doesn't do anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway and a lambda which query on it.
I have set the cache ttl on the API Gateway to the maximum (3600).

I'm testing the API from Postman.
My cache is working as querying multiple time the exact same url returns me the result quite fast.

On some conditions, I need the lambda to invalidate the cache for a specific key. So I deactivated "require authorization" under "Per-key cache invalidation" in the API Gateway stage editor, and I'm trying with Postman to do the same query and adding "Cache-Control: max-age=0" header as written here 
 under the "Invalidate an API Gateway 
 Cache Entry" section.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html

However, my cache doesn't seem to empty as querying multiple times is still as fast.

Comment: It seems possible that you *might* need to flush your cache once, after making the change, so that the system knows that the (subsequently) cached responses can be freely-invalidated.  Otherwise it might have cached the fact that they cannot be.  That's speculation, but possibly worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that but it had no effect. The http response was still slow on the first call and then fast, whether or not I add the Cache-Control header.

Comment: Did you confirm that API Gateway is caching the result from your integration endpoint? And did you wait until the cache is available on the stage before sending a cache invalidation request?

Comment: To be short : yes and yes. To check that API Gateway is caching : I run some queries ==> fast responses, then Flush Cache button and run one query ==> slow response, then run many queries ==> fast responses.
I waited until response was fast before sending invalidation request.

Comment: Confirm that your cache invalidation request is passing all of the same input parameters as the normal requests, especially those which map to the cache key.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem is? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @MikeDatAWS Yes it was the exact same query, I simply added the Cache-Control header.

Comment: @JAck28 I didn't find a solution sorry. It wasn't mandatory for my usecase so I juste gave up on it. Still interested if you find a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Postman silently overrides "Cache-Control" header value to "Cache-Control: no-cache". You are able to see it when press "Code" button. Try to use other tool, curl for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop Postman sending `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the settings:

[image]